# Compiling new package causing roscore command not found

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile a new package with catkin_make_isolated but after visibly successful installation my I receive roscore and catkin_make, etc command not found. My only option is to reload from an earlier backup to restore my ROS.

The steps I'm following:

1. Installing roscopter on Hydro from here: ( https://github.com/epsilonorion/roscopter/wiki )
2. I place the roscore source in the /src library
3. compile mavlink with `sudo python setup.py install`
4. Run catkin_make:

   ```
    catkin_make_isolated --pkg <my_package_name> --install
   ```
5. Roscore is still working until I don't restart, after that `command not found`

The .bashrc does refer to the install_isolated/setup.bash, still no roscore or catkin_make, etc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127971/compiling-new-package-causing-roscore-command-not-found/) by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-10**:
Which OS are you running? Have you installed ROS from debs or from source?

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-02-12**:
Sorry, I just saw this comment. The issue already got resolved (see details below), but in case others would read this later here is the answer to your question:
OS: Raspbian Wheezy on a Raspberry Pi
ROS is compiled from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems there was/is an issue with the roscopter install instructions (https://github.com/epsilonorion/roscopter/wiki):

...

- Navigate back to repo folder
- Checkout mavlink using submodule (shown below), or create a symlink to an existing mavlink build.

  - Run command 'git submodule init'
  - Run command 'git submodule update'
- To build mavlink, navigate to the "pymavlink" folder and run the command "sudo python setup.py install".

...

If you follow the above instructions word by word then the mavlink folder will be created in the roscopter folder causing the above issue.
You actually need to move the mavlink folder to roscopter/src and then compile it. It is strange that the compile did run through fine but resulted in ros setup files being changed, but in any way this seemed to solve it.

The instructions correctly should state:

...

- Navigate back to repo folder
- Navigate to src folder
- Checkout mavlink using submodule (shown below), or create a symlink to an existing mavlink build.

...

---

Originally posted by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) with karma: 218 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
You should probably file this as a bug against roscopter if you haven't yet.

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-02-11**:
Yes, I have already raised this question there too and now I'm asking them to update the instructions (see https://github.com/epsilonorion/roscopter/issues/2).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're building this as part of a complete installation of ROS from source, you probably shouldn't be using the `--pkg` option to `catkin_make_isolated`. I suspect it's compiling just that package and replacing your ROS install with only the package you specify.

Try building with:

```
catkin_make_isolated --install
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-02-11**:
Actually it looks that things go south even before I would get to the catkin-make-isolated --pkg part.
As soon as I compile mavlink (see instal instructions on Hydro here : https://github.com/epsilonorion/roscopter/wiki ) and restart there is no catkin_make or roscore, etc.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
It sounds like something you're doing along the way is accidentally overwriting the setup files. Try doing an `ls -l` on install_isolated/setup.bash after every installation step, and look for changes in size and timestamp.

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-02-11**:
You are right, I think I just figured it out. There was an error in the roscopter package install instructions - see details in my answer below.